# javascript find() function without jquery

Tags: javascript

I love to trying something new. So, I decided to make my own function **without** using jquery. I'm trying to build  `find()`

So, this is my code :

```js
function $(el) {
  var firstChar = el.charAt(0),
      id = document.getElementById(el.slice(1));

  switch (firstChar) {
    case "#":
      return id;
      break;
  }
}

function find(el, loop) {
  return getElementsByTagName(el)[loop];
}

$("#test").find("h1", 0).innerHTML = "some text";
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <h1>test one</h1>
  <h2>test two</h2>
</div>
```

It's not working, in my dreamweaver error log, it said that `getElementsByTagName` is not defined.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: try using document.getElementsByTagName(el)

Comment: i already try it, it does not working also. because document has been declared at first of $() function

Comment: you can do it directly id you still want to use it as a function,,

function find(el, loop) {return document.getElementsByTagName(el)[loop];}
find("h1",0).innerHTML = "some text";

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/a/getElementsByTagName) has to be called on a DOMElement. e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName`  or `yourElement.getElementsByTagName`.

An equivalent to `find` would be [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
 document.getElementById("#test").getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "some text";
```

OR

```
 document.getElementById("#test").querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "some text";
```

OR

```
 document.getElementById("#test").querySelectorAll("h1")[0].innerHTML = "some text";
```

A simple implementation, similar to the way it is implemented in jQuery, but be award that is just a proof of concept code, nothing to be used in production code:

```js
function $(selector) {

    function ResultSet(elements) {
        var i;

        //make ResultSet to an array like object
        this.length = elements.length;

        //copy the values from elements to this 
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i] = elements[i];
        }

    }

    ResultSet.prototype.find = function (selector) {
        var completeList = [],
            result, i;

        //loop through each element
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            //find the find the matching elements using the stored element as base for the query
            result = this[i].querySelectorAll(selector);
            result = Array.prototype.slice.call(result); //convert NodeList to array
            completeList = completeList.concat(result); //concat the result
        };

        //return the collected elements as new result set
        return new ResultSet(completeList);
    };


    return new ResultSet( document.querySelectorAll(selector) );
}


$("#test").find("h1")[0].innerHTML = "some text";
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <h1>test one</h1>
  <h2>test two</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working all of them, how could i build find() function on this .getElementsByTagName("h1")[0] so, i will not repeat them all over again? thanks t.niese

Comment: what do you mean with `[...]how could i build find() function on this .getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]`

Comment: i mean, how could i make shorter statement with a function, instead call it over and over again like this statement .getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML

Comment: @ChingChing I edited the answer. But as I mentioned this I not code that should be used in production, it is just to illustrate how it could be done.

Comment: fantastic! i learn a lot of things on your solution. thank you so much t.niese!!!!