# Mimicking $ jQuery selector with forEach yields undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectors-api

I know there are a lot of lightweight JavaScript libraries that do the job, but for my curiosity, I tried this:

```
function $(a) {

    b = document.querySelectorAll(a);

  [].forEach.call(b, function(d) {

    return d

  });
}

$(".tobered,#illbered").style.border = '1px solid #f00'
```

And of course my console said: `TypeError: $(...) is undefined`.

**Lets do clearer :**

Simplified 'function' :

`var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)`

Call which works :

`$(".tobered,#illbered")[0].style.border = '1px solid #f00'`

Call I need but in one line :

```
 $(".tobered,#illbered")[0].style.border = '1px solid #f00'
 $(".tobered,#illbered")[1].style.border = '1px solid #f00'
 $(".tobered,#illbered")[2].style.border = '1px solid #f00'
 $(".tobered,#illbered")[...].style.border = '1px solid #f00'
```

**Clearer**

How does this works ? https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Can't figure it out by reading the `jquery.js` file

Comment: There's absolutely no point in doing that initial split on commas, because `.querySelectorAll()` understands that already. The error you're getting is caused by the lack of a `return` value from your `$()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`return\` keyword mean inside \`forEach\` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653612/what-does-return-keyword-mean-inside-foreach-function)

Comment: You're right @Pointy I'm stupid huh. Thx for the duplicate link, I check that

Comment: I don't think you're stupid :)

Comment: @Xufox I don't see the link between this possible duplicate and my question. No matter I use `some()`, `every()`, `for`, `while`, `do`... methods, and I have no `break` issues. However, I might not understand well the usage of `return` in this case.

Comment: @LoargAnn Not using `forEach` would be a step in the right direction. This is part of the problem. The other big problem, already pointed out by Pointy, that there’s no `return` directly in your `$` function — it just selects things, iterates over them, but does nothing with the elements after that. Actually, `map` is the most appropriate Array function here. But the most appropriate thing to do would be to just use `document.querySelectorAll(".tobered, #illbered")`.

Comment: @Xufox Oh ! I have never heard about `map` :) Thx ! About using the whole `document.querySelectorAll` I know that, it's a curiosity question. It's not the first time I'm asking myself how to pass an `Array` of multiple elements and apply them actions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer to [javascript find() function without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774170/javascript-find-function-without-jquery/33774206#33774206). That's not exactly your question, but might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a conceptual misunderstanding there.

`$` is *declared* but its return value is *undefined*. It doesn't return anything. Therefore you can't do `undefined.style`.

But even if it returned something, you would be accessing the `style` property of whatever it returned. The function has already been executed at that point.

```
function $(a) {
    b = document.querySelectorAll(a);
    //Calling forEach of an empty array
    //              Each call with b as this
    //                 And the function as parameter
    [].forEach.call(b, function(d) {
        //This actually will never run because there're no elements
        //But if it did, d would be returned to the forEach call
        //and forEach wouldn't do anything with the returned value
        return d
    });
    //The forEach calls returned nothing
    //Function ended and nothing is returned
}
var r=$(...);
//r $(...) is undefined
```

Note that jQuery uses methods to achieve this, for example

```
$(a).style(b);
```

Where `$(a)` returns an object, and the method *of the returned object* `style()` applies the styles `b` to the selected elements, which are also defined somewhat in the returned object.

So the way to do what you want would be to return some object in `$()` with properties and *methods* to apply the styles. Or to have a single function that does everything like `$(selector,styles)`, or two functions, one `$()` to select (or just use querySelectorAll) and `style()` that does the forEach thing (like `style(elems,styles)`).

Comment: You're right, jQuery uses methods, I think I tried to use vanilla JS and jQuery syntax which clearly doesn't works. Thx for your answer, I know how to do that right now :)

Comment: Hey Gabriel and @t.niese, I added an answer with my progress, based on your advices, but I still have some issues. Can you help ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on *t-niese*'s comment and *Gabriel*'s answer.

Is that elegant ? Because it's working for me :)

```
const $ = function(a) {

  let b = [];

  function Reach(els) {
    if (typeof a == "string") {
      b.length = els.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = els[i];
      }
    } else {
      b.push(els);
    }
  }

  Reach.prototype.css = function(prop, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      b[i].style[prop] = val;
    }
  }

  Reach.prototype.on = function(evt, fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      if (b[i].addEventListener) {
        b[i].addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
      } else if (b[i].attachEvent) {
        b[i].attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }

 if (typeof a == "string") {
   return new Reach(document.querySelectorAll(a))
 } else {
   return new Reach(a)
 }

$(".tobered, #illbered").css("color","red")

$(window).on("click",function(){
  alert('Red is definitely a beautiful color')
})
```

However I'm doubtful about the fact of using `for` and `(typeof a == "string") ?` twice.

Plus, I lost the ability to use `$("#id")[0]` as a simple selector. If there's no methods, it doesn't works.

I tried so hard to find how to determine if a method is called with `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()` and `instanceof` to return something else, but I failed.

So right know, I have to use another "function" :

`const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)`

Comment: You can have an _object_ with both numeric and string named properties. If `$` returns such object, you could do both `$(..)[0]` (which should be instances of `$` representing each element) and `$(..).css(..)`. The last `typeof a=="string"` is fine, but the first one, inside `Reach()` doesn't make sense. If `els` is a string, the `for` will iterate each character. But `els` will never be other than a list of `Element` because of how you instantiate it. Another thing, remember that `let` is ES6.

Comment: Thx ! It was obvious for the first `typeof` check, I have to stop coding at late hours ^^ But `$(..)[0]` returns `undefined` because $(..) methods returns the object `__proto__` with `Reach`, `css` and `on` :(

Comment: Nope, `$(window)` not being taken without the first `typeof`.
See before:  https://jsfiddle.net/wf48ukrp/4/
And after: https://jsfiddle.net/wf48ukrp/9/

Comment: The problem is not the `typeof`, but that you aren't checking if what you got in `els` is an array or a single element. You are trying to pass `window` through the loop. The `$(...)[0]` thing doesn't work because you're storing the elements in `b`... You have to either store the elements in the object (`this`) or implement a `get(i)` method like jQuery (which would be the right thing to do).